# Añadir array a una sesión

Tags: php, array

En el siguiente código estoy intentando añadir un array a un array de sesión pero no me muestra el array generado cuando lo imprimo.

El código tiene dos campos de formulario nombre y apellidos que al introducirlos deberia guardarlos en la sesion '$_SESSION['datos']'.

```
<?php session_start();?>
<html>
<body>

    <?php

    echo '<FORM ACTION="simuladorExames.php" METHOD="GET">
                Introduce el nombre:<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="nombre"><br>
                Introduce el apellido:<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="apellido"><br>
                <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="accion" VALUE="registroDatos"><br>
                <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Enviar">
           </FORM>';

        if(!existenDatosEnSesion()){

            inicializaDatosPrecargados();
        }

        function existenDatosEnSesion(){
            return isset($_SESSION['data']) && is_array($_SESSION['data']);
        }

        // Cargamos los datos precargados.
        function inicializaDatosPrecargados(){

                $persona1= [
                    'nombre' => 'persona1',
                    'apellido' => 'persona1'
                ];

                $persona2= [
                    'nombre' => 'persona2',
                    'apellido' => 'persona2'
                ];

                $_SESSION['datos'] = [ $persona1, $persona2 ];
            }

        function imprimeListaAlumnos(){

            $datos = $_SESSION['datos'];

            foreach ( $datos as $alumno ) {

                echo $alumno['nombre']. " " . $alumno['apellido'];
                echo "<br>";
            }
        }

        // Imprimimos los datos precargados.
        imprimeListaAlumnos();


        //Si el boton enviar es accionado y los campos nombre y apellido estan rellanados debería añadir el nuevo alumno.
        function procesarDatosNuevos(){

            if($_GET['accion'] == "registroDatos"){

                if($_GET['nombre'] != NULL and $_GET['apellido'] != NULL ){

                        $_SESSION['datos'][$nuevoAlumno] = array('nombre' => $_GET['nombre'], 'apellido' => $_GET['apellido']);

                    }
                }
            }

       //resultado

       //persona1 persona1
       //persona2 persona2
       // Aqui deberia ir el nuevo array añadido.

    ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://web.archive.org/web/20080707052007/http://www.phpriot.com/articles/intro-php-sessions/7

Comment: ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($_SESSION);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen varios errores en el código:

1. Cuando realizas la condición:
   `if(!existenDatosEnSesion()){`, verificas que exista el
   index `$_SESSION['data']`, cuando nunca usas ese index
   `data`, si no el index `datos` por lo tanto
   siempre se va a cumplir esa condición.
2. La función `procesarDatosNuevos` nunca se ejecuta, por lo
   tanto nunca va a realizar la acción que declaras.
3. La función `imprimeListaAlumnos` debe ejecutarse luego de ejecutar
   `procesarDatosNuevos`.
4. La variable `$nuevoAlumno` en la línea
   `$_SESSION['datos'][$nuevoAlumno]` no está definida.

Te propongo el siguiente cambio:

```
function imprimeListaAlumnos() {

        $datos = $_SESSION['datos'];

        foreach ( $datos as $alumno ) {

            echo $alumno['nombre']. " " . $alumno['apellido'];
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }


    //Si el boton enviar es accionado y los campos nombre y apellido estan rellanados debería añadir el nuevo alumno.
    function procesarDatosNuevos(){

        if($_GET['accion'] == "registroDatos"){

            if($_GET['nombre'] != NULL and $_GET['apellido'] != NULL ){

                    $_SESSION['datos'][] = array('nombre' => $_GET['nombre'], 'apellido' => $_GET['apellido']);

                }
            }
        }

    // Procesamos los datos
    procesarDatosNuevos();

    // Imprimimos los datos precargados.
    imprimeListaAlumnos();
```